# If $[G:H]=2$ then $|x^H|=|x^G|$ or $|x^H|=\frac 12|x^G|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $H\le G$, $x\in H$, if $[G:H]=2$ then $|x^H|=|x^G|$ or $|x^H|=\frac 12|x^G|$.

We already know that $x^G=\frac{|G|}{|C_G(x)|}$ and that $[H:C_H(x)]=|x^H|$, then: $[G:C_H(x)]=[G:H][H:C_H(x)]=2|x^H|$. 

On the other hand, we know that if $H\le G$ and $x\in H$ then $C_H(x)=H\cap C_G(x)$, hence we can assure that $C_H(x)\le C_G(x)\le G$. Thereupon $[G:C_H(x)]=[G:C_G(x)][C_G(x):C_H(x)]$, but we know that $[G:C_H(x)]=2|x^H|$, then if we consider $\alpha:=[C_G(x):C_H(x)]$, we have that $2|x^H|=|x^G|\alpha$, so that would mean that to get what we want $\alpha=1\;or\;2$.

I don't know how to get that, I know we haven't used that $H$ is abelian but still I can't come up with something useful.

---

**Note**: $y\in x^H \Leftrightarrow y=hxh^{-1}, h\in H$

Comment: What's the source of this problem?

Comment: @Babgen it's from a list of exercises to practice the professor gave us, I don't know where she got them, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $[G:H]=2$, $H$ is normal in $G$. Hence
$$
\frac{|C_G(x)|}{|C_G(x)\cap H|}=\frac{|C_G(x)H|}{|H|},
$$
i.e.
$$
\frac{|C_G(x)|}{|C_H(x)|}=\frac{|C_G(x)H|}{|H|},
$$
i.e.
$$
\frac{2|x^H|}{|x^G|}=\frac{|C_G(x)H|}{|H|}.
$$
If $C_G(x)\subseteq H$ then $2|x^H|=|x^G|$, else $C_G(x) H=G$ and $|x^H|=|x^G|$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just one thing, why $C_G(x)\subset H$, and not $H\subset C_G(x)$?

Comment: I slightly corrected: $C_G(x)\subseteq H$. If $C_G(x)\supset H$ then $C_G(x)=G$.